# How to play part of an audio in Love2D?

Tags: lua, love2d

Now this is my program at the moment and it plays the audio specified.

```
sound = love.audio.newSource('sound.wav',)
sound:play()
```

But what happens is it plays the whole audio whereas I want to only play part of it. Is there any way I can do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and simplest way to play a part of some audio file is to have that part in a separate audio file.

Otherwise you must use `sound:stop()`  or `sound:pause()` depending on what you want. But then you have to care about proper timing.

https://love2d.org/wiki/love.audio